# Move modifications made in develop branch into a new git-flow feature branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm using git-flow for my projects, and have started a rather complicated set of changes in the develop branch, which appear to take longer than I expected first.

I wish I had done this in a feature branch, since I'd like to make a new release with other changes. How can I move these uncommitted changes into a new git-flow feature branch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**If you've made no commits**

If you simply have a dirty working copy, just act like you are about to start a new feature:

```
git flow feature start awesomeness
git commit -va
```

**If you *did* make some commits**

If there are commits in develop that should have been in your feature branch, the above steps are the same. In addition though you'll (possibly - this isn't required) want to reset your develop branch back to where it was before you started committing the changes for your feature branch, which you can do with:

```
git flow feature start awesomeness
git commit -va
git checkout develop
git reset origin/develop --hard
```

Comment: I didn't know the feature could be started after the uncommitted changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
git checkout where-you-should-have-made-your-feature-branch
git branch feature-branch
git checkout feature-branch
foreach commit in commits-that-should-have-been-on-your-feature-branch:
    # do this for each commit in chronological order
    git cherry-pick commit
```

Now it depends on whether you've already pushed your develop branch to a public repository or not. If everything is still private, and you want to rewrite history:

```
git checkout develop-branch
foreach commit in commits-that-should-have-been-on-your-feature-branch:
    # do this for each commit in reverse chronological order
    git rebase --onto commit~1 commit develop-branch
```

If you don't want to rewrite history:

```
git checkout develop-branch
foreach commit in commits-that-should-have-been-on-your-feature-branch:
    # do this for each commit in reverse chronological order
    git revert commit
```

And that should do it.

Comment: git rebase in a loop seems a bit unnecessary/clumsy - what's the idea there?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but nothing had been committed yet. The solution was easier than that.